# Losing Active Status of Category in Pagination

Tags: categories, pagination

I'm using this code to display the active category as the title of the page before the channel entries are listed out, however, if you go to the next page using the pagination the category seems to lose it's active status and nothing is returned. Any suggestions?

Example:

1st page returns: Category > Active Category Name

2nd page returns: Category >

1st page URL: /sustainability/stories_and_video/category/pillars_passion_for_people

2nd page URL: /sustainability/stories_and_video/category/pillars_passion_for_people/P3

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="stories" disable="member_data" orderby="article_publish_date" sort="desc" limit="3" pagination="bottom"}
  {if count == 1}
      <h2>
           Category > {categories}{if active}{category_name}{/if}{/categories}
      </h2>
  {/if}
  <div class="pageBlock newsBlock">
    {if story_image != ""}<img class="sus_small_img" src="{story_image:small_images}" />{/if}
    <h2><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h2>
    {story_blurb}
    <span id="more"><a href="  {url_title_path='sustainability/story_detail'}">Read more</a></span>
</div>
{paginate}
    <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the active variable before so I'm not sure why it's not working with pagination, however you should be able to use the segment variable in your conditional instead:

```
{categories}
    {if category_url_title == segment_4}{category_name}{/if}
{/categories}
```

Comment: I figured that would be my work around if I couldn't resolve this, but just thought I would throw it out there in the interest of keeping everything as dynamic as possible. :) Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Okay, I responded to this before I had my coffee... this solution IS dynamic and is exactly what I needed. Thank you!